# Is it possible to create a custom file type for a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like if someone clicks File -> New..., they get another option for a particular file type that opens with some initial content, like a snippet but predefined as part of our custom extension code.

[image]

Comment: you can use [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates), it replaces `Ctrl+N`

Comment: Needs to be part of our extension, so needs to use vs code apis, not a separate extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add "menus" section to the  "package.json" file of the extension like the following :

```
 "menus": {
        "file/newFile": [
            {                   
      "command": "myExtension.newDocument"
            }
        ]
    }
```

and in the "command" section :

```
"command": [
    {
        "command": "myExtension.newDocument",
        "title": "New Document ...",

    }
        ],
```

and finally in the "activationEvents" section:

```
"activationEvents": ["onCommand:myExtension.newDocument"],
```

In addition, the command itself should be defined and registered in the code (extensions.ts), for example :

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)
.....
const newDocument = async () => {..........};
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.newDocument'
, newDocument));
.....
}
```

Hope this help !